# Postgis to KML, including color field

Tags: kml, postgis

I would like to export a Postgis table to a KML file. I am using the ogr2ogr program for this, but my problem is that I want to include the color associated with each linestring in the output KML.
Is this possible? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe that this is possible. You would need to write a plpgsql function to do this using the ST_AsKML function in postgis and concatenating the color attribute data around it or use the xml functions built into Postgres, see: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-xml.html in conjunction with ST_AsKML. There is an interesting example here, http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/267-Creating-GeoJSON-Feature-Collections-with-JSON-and-PostGIS-functions.html, of how to use ST_AsGeoJSON to add extra attributes other than just the coordinates to the output.

There is also a Python library, from Google themselves, to manipulate KML, so this might be a good bet: http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/introducing-pykml-python-library-for.html

I realize that this is not what you asked, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you that will help me :D. And sorry for my english :Z

Comment: @user3636199 I am sure your English is a lot better than my attempts at whatever is your native language :D. I understood you question without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

An example for a road database is as follows:

```
  SELECT ST_AsKml(ST_AsText(geom)) FROM myRoadTable where ref="MyRoadName";
```